# editableSelect() not working in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, typescript

I have a problem with jquery editableSelect() in typescript. I want to make the select dropdown list but with input, so the user can input their things and they get to search in the list. I don't want to use dataList because I can't style them. Do you have any ideas what's wrong? Or you can recommend me different ideas?

```
import React from "react";
import $ from 'jquery';
import "./Search.scss";

const Search = () => {
    return (
        <div className="search">
            <div className="search__search-bar">
                <i className="fa fa-search" />
                <select id="editable" className="search__search-bar__input">
                    <option>Option 1</option>
                    <option>Option 2</option>
                    <option>Option 3</option>
                    <option>Option 4</option>
                    <option>Option 5</option>
                    <option>Option 6</option>
                </select>

                <div className="search__search-bar__delete">
                    <i className="fa fa-times" />
                </div>
            </div>
            {($('#editable') as any).editableSelect()}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Search;
```

```
TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...)(...).$ is undefined
Search
D:/Dane/Projekty/Zadania_boosttypers/boosttypers/src/components/shop/search/Search.tsx:20

  17 |          </select>
  18 | 
  19 |          <div className="search__search-bar__delete">
> 20 |              <i className="fa fa-times" />
     | ^  21 |          </div>
  22 |      </div>
  23 |      {($('#editable') as any).$.editableSelect()}
```

Comment: i would recommend you not to use jquery in 2019

Comment: +1 on what @JurajKocan wrote. There should be non-jquery alternatives out there. If you insist using Editable Select, can you please try importing jquery that way: `import * as $ from 'jquery'` instead of `import $ from 'jquery';`?

Comment: i tried import * as $ from 'jquery but it's not working